# Convert seconds into days ,hours, minutes, and seconds in python

Tags: python

how can i convert 200 seconds  into  in days, hours, minutes, seconds in python (the output should be single line containing like D,H,M,S print only  the non zero values

Comment: How would you do that by hand if you were asked to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)